# Replacement power cable for Mindstorms RCX

Tags: rcx

I have an old Mindstorms 1.5 [RCX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Mindstorms#RCX).

The plastic on the power cables has degraded, and they short out and don't work well.

[These](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=300653416462&ssPageName=ADME%3aB%3aWNASIF%3aAU:1123#ht_949wt_907) look like they would work as replacements, but I'm not exactly sure. I contacted the seller but they didn't respond.

Will these work as replacement RCX power cables?

Answer (score 8):

The cables you point out are newer Power Function cables and are ill-suited for 9V usage such as with the original Mindstorms kits. Technically, you could daisy-chain two of them and it would work, but that's probably not the best solution.

Here is a bigger illustration of the cable, courtesy [Philo](http://www.philohome.com/pf/pf.htm):

[image: ![PF extansion cable]()]

You can clearly see that only one end of the cable has a 9V connector on the bottom.

I would advise you to check [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=Electric%2C+Wire+with+Brick+2+x+2+x+2%2F3+Pair%2C) instead, you should find plenty of seller there, possibly in your own country.